# Recyclerview not refreshing

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-recyclerview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I am working on a project where user adds data at runtime.The problem is whenever user inserts the fist element it is adding to the database and displaying in recyclerview.But when user adds more data the recyclerview keeps displaying firstelement over and over again.
If the user adds `Apple` it is adding to database and recyclerview is displaying `Apple`.Now if the user adds `orange` it is adding to database but the recyclerview is displaying `Apple` two times.
I am using Cursorloader to load data,Contentprovider to add data,and CustomCursoradapter(https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59) to set the data to recyclerview

**`addDetails()` method execute when user adds data**

```
public class AddLog extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    TextView TotalAmount,Date;
    EditText name,mobile,city,detailname,detailamount;
    RecyclerView adddetailtolist;
    DetailsAdapter adapter;
    Intent returnback;
    double totamount;
    long logid;
    String Debt = "Debt";
    String Paid = "Paid";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_log);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.addlogtoolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Add Log");
        returnback = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        logid = intent.getExtras().getLong("ID");
        TotalAmount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalAmount);
        Date = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.addlogDate);
        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.AddName);
        mobile = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.AddPhone);
        city = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Addcity);
        detailname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Detailname);
        detailamount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Detailamount);
        adddetailtolist = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.addloglist);
        Date.setText(getDate());
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1,null,this);
        adapter = new DetailsAdapter(this,null);
        adddetailtolist.setAdapter(adapter);
        adddetailtolist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }
    private String getDate()
    {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE,dd-MMM-yyyy");
        String date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        return date;
    }
    public void addDetails(View view)
    {
        String Name = detailname.getText().toString();
        String Amount = detailamount.getText().toString();
        String date = Date.getText().toString();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DataProvider.Dname,Name);
        contentValues.put(DataProvider.DCategory,Debt);
        contentValues.put(DataProvider.Damount,Amount);
        contentValues.put(DataProvider.Ddate,date);
        contentValues.put(DataProvider.Per_In,logid);
        Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(DataProvider.ContentUri_Details,contentValues);
        Toast.makeText(AddLog.this, uri.toString()+"Value Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        NumberFormat currency = changeamount();
        TotalAmount.setText(currency.format(getAmount()));
    }

    private double getAmount()
    {
        ContentProviderClient client = getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient(DataProvider.ContentUri_Details);
        SQLiteDatabase db = ((DataProvider)client.getLocalContentProvider()).sqLiteDatabase;
        String query = "SELECT SUM(DAmount) FROM Details WHERE Per_In = "+logid;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        double amount = cursor.getDouble(0);
        cursor.close();
        client.release();
        return amount;
    }


    public NumberFormat changeamount()
    {
        Locale locale = new Locale("en","IN");
        NumberFormat currencyformat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
        return currencyformat;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuinflate = getMenuInflater();
        menuinflate.inflate(R.menu.addlogmenu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.done:
                saveData();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void saveData()
    {
        String name1 = name.getText().toString();
        String phone  = mobile.getText().toString();
        String address = city.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name1)||TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)||TextUtils.isEmpty(address))
        {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name1))
            {
                name.setError("Feild can not be Empty");
            }
           else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phone))
            {
                mobile.setError("Feild can not be Empty");
            }
           else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(address))
            {
                city.setError("Feild can not be Empty");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(DataProvider.Pname,name1);
            values.put(DataProvider.Pphone,phone);
            values.put(DataProvider.Paddress,address);
            values.put(DataProvider.PCategory,"Debt");
            values.put(DataProvider.Pamount,totamount);
            String where = DataProvider.PID+"=?";
            String[] whereargs = {String.valueOf(logid)};
           int a = getContentResolver().update(DataProvider.ContentUri_Person,values,where,whereargs);
            Toast.makeText(AddLog.this, String.valueOf(1)+"Value updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(returnback);
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(final int id, Bundle args)
    {
        String[] Projection = new String[]{DataProvider.DID,DataProvider.Dname,DataProvider.DCategory,DataProvider.Damount,DataProvider.Ddate};
        String selection = DataProvider.Per_In+"=?";
        String[] selectionargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(logid)};
        return new CursorLoader(this,DataProvider.ContentUri_Details,Projection,selection,selectionargs,null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data)
    {
       adapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader)
    {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

**Content Provider class:**

```
public class DataProvider extends ContentProvider
{
    static final String ProviderName = "com.example.mrudu.accounts.provider";
    static final String URLPerson = "content://"+ProviderName+"/Person_Detail";
    static final String URLDetails = "content://"+ProviderName+"/Details";
    static final Uri ContentUri_Person = Uri.parse(URLPerson);
    static final Uri ContentUri_Details = Uri.parse(URLDetails);
//Tables
private static String PTableName = "Person_Detail";
private static String DTableName = "Details";

public static long insertId = 0;

//Person_Detail Coloumns
public static String PID = "_id";
public static String Pname = "PName";
public static String Pphone = "PMobile";
public static String Paddress = "PCity";
public static String PCategory = "PCategory";
public static String Pamount = "PAmount";

//Details coloumn
public static String DID = "_id";
public static String Dname = "DName";
public static String Damount = "DAmount";
public static String Ddate = "DDate";
public static String DCategory = "DCategory";
public static String Per_In = "Per_In";

private static final int Person = 1;
private static final int Person_ID = 2;
private static final int Details = 3;
private static final int Details_Id = 4;

static UriMatcher uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
static
{
    uriMatcher.addURI(ProviderName,PTableName,Person);
    uriMatcher.addURI(ProviderName,PTableName+"/#",Person_ID);
    uriMatcher.addURI(ProviderName,DTableName,Details);
    uriMatcher.addURI(ProviderName,DTableName+"/#",Details_Id);
}

public static SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
private static String Databasename = "Accounts";
private static int DatabaseVersion = 1;

private class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, Databasename, null, DatabaseVersion);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
    {
        String Create_Person = " Create Table "+PTableName+"("+PID+" INTEGER PRIMARYKEY ,"+Pname+" TEXT ,"+Pphone+" TEXT ,"+Paddress+" TEXT ,"+PCategory+" TEXT ,"+Pamount+" REAL"+")";
        String Create_Details = " Create Table "+DTableName+"("+DID+" INTEGER PRIMARYKEY ,"+Dname+" TEXT ,"+DCategory+" TEXT ,"+Damount+" REAl ,"+Ddate+" TEXT ,"+Per_In+" INTEGER )";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(Create_Person);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(Create_Details);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1)
    {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("Drop TABLE if exists"+PTableName);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("Drop TABLE if exists"+DTableName);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreate()
{
    Context context = getContext();
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    sqLiteDatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return (sqLiteDatabase==null)?false:true;
}
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values)
{
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri))
    {
        case Person:
            long rowId = sqLiteDatabase.insert(PTableName,null,values);
            insertId = rowId;
            if (rowId>0)
            {
               Uri _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContentUri_Person,rowId);
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri,null);
                return _uri;
            }
            break;
        case Details:
            long rowId1 = sqLiteDatabase.insert(DTableName,null,values);
            if (rowId1>0)
            {
                Uri _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContentUri_Details,rowId1);
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri,null);
                return _uri;
            }
            break;
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                    String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)
{
    SQLiteQueryBuilder sqLiteQueryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri))
    {
        case Person_ID:
            sqLiteQueryBuilder.setTables(PTableName);
            sqLiteQueryBuilder.appendWhere(PID+ "="+ uri.getPathSegments().get(1));
            break;
        case Person:
            sqLiteQueryBuilder.setTables(PTableName);
            break;
        case Details_Id:
            sqLiteQueryBuilder.setTables(DTableName);
            sqLiteQueryBuilder.appendWhere(Per_In +"="+ uri.getPathSegments().get(1));
            break;
        case Details:
            sqLiteQueryBuilder.setTables(DTableName);
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteQueryBuilder.query(sqLiteDatabase,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,sortOrder);
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(),uri);
    return cursor;

}
@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
                  String[] selectionArgs)
{
    int count = 0;
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri))
    {
        case Person:
            count = sqLiteDatabase.update(PTableName,values,selection,selectionArgs);
            break;
        case Person_ID:
            count = sqLiteDatabase.update(PTableName,values,PID+" = "+uri.getPathSegments().get(1)+(!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)?" AND (" + selection + ')':""),selectionArgs);
            break;
        case Details:
            count = sqLiteDatabase.update(DTableName,values,selection,selectionArgs);
            break;
        case Details_Id:
            count = sqLiteDatabase.update(DTableName,values,Per_In+" = "+uri.getPathSegments().get(1)+(!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)?" AND (" + selection + ')':""),selectionArgs);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri );
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);
    return count;
}
@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    // Implement this to handle requests to delete one or more rows.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    // TODO: Implement this to handle requests for the MIME type of the data
    // at the given URI.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

}

**Detils class:**

```
public class Details
{
    String name,date;
    double amount;

    public Details(String name, double amount, String date) {
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Details() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public static Details from(Cursor cursor)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            Details details = new Details(cursor.getString(1),cursor.getDouble(3),cursor.getString(4));
            return details;
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

**Adapter class :**

```
public class DetailsAdapter extends CursorRecyclerViewAdapter<DetailsAdapter.View_Holder>
{

    public DetailsAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor);
    }
    public static class View_Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView mName,mAmount,mDate;
        public View_Holder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            mName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.DetailName);
            mAmount = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.DetailAmount);
            mDate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.DetailDate);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public DetailsAdapter.View_Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.addloglistlayout,parent,false);
        View_Holder viewHolder = new View_Holder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DetailsAdapter.View_Holder viewHolder, Cursor cursor)
    {
        Details details = Details.from(cursor);
        viewHolder.mName.setText(details.getName());
        viewHolder.mAmount.setText(String.valueOf(details.getAmount()));
        viewHolder.mDate.setText(details.getDate());
    }
}
```

**Cursor Recyclerview Adapter class:**

```
public abstract class CursorRecyclerViewAdapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {
    private Context mContext;

    private Cursor mCursor;

    private boolean mDataValid;

    private int mRowIdColumn;

    private DataSetObserver mDataSetObserver;

    public CursorRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        mContext = context;
        mCursor = cursor;
        mDataValid = cursor != null;
        mRowIdColumn = mDataValid ? mCursor.getColumnIndex("_id") : -1;
        mDataSetObserver = new NotifyingDataSetObserver();
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
        }
    }

    public Cursor getCursor() {
        return mCursor;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mDataValid && mCursor != null) {
            return mCursor.getCount();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        if (mDataValid && mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            return mCursor.getLong(mRowIdColumn);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void setHasStableIds(boolean hasStableIds) {
        super.setHasStableIds(true);
    }

    public abstract void onBindViewHolder(VH viewHolder, Cursor cursor);

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VH viewHolder, int position) {
        if (!mDataValid) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("this should only be called when the cursor is valid");
        }
        if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("couldn't move cursor to position " + position);
        }
        onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, mCursor);
    }

    /**
     * Change the underlying cursor to a new cursor. If there is an existing cursor it will be
     * closed.
     */
    public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        Cursor old = swapCursor(cursor);
        if (old != null) {
            old.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Swap in a new Cursor, returning the old Cursor.  Unlike
     * {@link #changeCursor(Cursor)}, the returned old Cursor is <em>not</em>
     * closed.
     */
    public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
        if (newCursor == mCursor) {
            return null;
        }
        final Cursor oldCursor = mCursor;
        if (oldCursor != null && mDataSetObserver != null) {
            oldCursor.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
        }
        mCursor = newCursor;
        if (mCursor != null) {
            if (mDataSetObserver != null) {
                mCursor.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
            }
            mRowIdColumn = newCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id");
            mDataValid = true;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            mRowIdColumn = -1;
            mDataValid = false;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            //There is no notifyDataSetInvalidated() method in RecyclerView.Adapter
        }
        return oldCursor;
    }

    private class NotifyingDataSetObserver extends DataSetObserver {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            mDataValid = true;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated() {
            super.onInvalidated();
            mDataValid = false;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            //There is no notifyDataSetInvalidated() method in RecyclerView.Adapter
        }
    }
}
```

***Thank you***

Comment: Can you please show me your CursorRecyclerViewAdapter Class Code ?

Comment: @Vickyexpert   I just added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `from` method in `Details` causing issue due to  `cursor.moveToFirst();` and `do-while` loop. change it as:

```
public static Details from(Cursor cursor)
    {
      Details details = new Details(cursor.getString(1),
                                    cursor.getDouble(3),
                                    cursor.getString(4));
      return details;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man..It worked.But i have another problem As you can see in the code i have two activities `MainActivity` and `Addlogactivity` i am updating a data in `Addlogactivity` which should be displayed in `mainactivity` recyclerview the data is updating in database but the value in mainactivity recyclerview is not changing.Please can you help me with this too.

Comment: @MallisettiMrudhuhas: ok but instead of making this question too big i suggest you make a new question for next issue with relevant code including  MainActivity code. and share link with me i will sure try to help

Comment: Here is the link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475854/recyclerview-not-updating-data-from-another-activity

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your adapter and all, so you are already moving your cursor to particular position from Adapter, so you don't need to set it moveToFist, so just remove the line cursor.moveToFirst() from Details Class and check result.

Comment: i have another problem As you can see in the code i have two activities MainActivity and Addlogactivity i am updating a data in Addlogactivity which should be displayed in mainactivity recyclerview the data is updating in database but the value in mainactivity recyclerview is not changing.Please can you help me with this too.I can ask this as another question.But it is saying that i have to ask question only after 90 min

Comment: Ok, does your data updating in database ?

Comment: ok then try to write below code in your main activity onResume method, and then check

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
   
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged

}

Comment: Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475854/recyclerview-not-updating-data-from-another-activity