# How to update Recyclerview data from another activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two activities MainActivity and Addlogactivity i am updating a data in Addlogactivity which should be displayed in mainactivity recyclerview the data is not updating in database

**MianActivityClass :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Intent addDisplay;
    Mainrow_Adapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        addDisplay = new Intent(this,AddLog.class);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.maintoolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Account's");
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1,null,this);
        adapter = new Mainrow_Adapter(this,null);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
    public void createID(View view)
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DataProvider.Pname,"1");
        values.put(DataProvider.Pphone,"1");
        values.put(DataProvider.Paddress,"1");
        values.put(DataProvider.PCategory,"1");
        values.put(DataProvider.Pamount,"1");
        getContentResolver().insert(DataProvider.ContentUri_Person,values);
        long id = DataProvider.insertId;
        addDisplay.putExtra("ID",id);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(id), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(addDisplay);
        finish();
    }

 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        String[] Prjection = {DataProvider.PID,DataProvider.Pname,DataProvider.Pphone,DataProvider.Paddress,DataProvider.PCategory,DataProvider.Pamount};
        return new CursorLoader(this,DataProvider.ContentUri_Person,Prjection,null,null,null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data)
    {
        adapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader)
    {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

**AddLog activity class :**

```
public class AddLog extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    TextView TotalAmount,Date;
    EditText name,mobile,city,detailname,detailamount;
    RecyclerView adddetailtolist;
    DetailsAdapter adapter;
    Intent returnback;
    double totamount;
    long logid;
    String Debt = "Debt";
    String Paid = "Paid";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_log);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.addlogtoolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Add Log");
        returnback = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        logid = intent.getExtras().getLong("ID");
        TotalAmount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalAmount);
        Date = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.addlogDate);
        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.AddName);
        mobile = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.AddPhone);
        city = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Addcity);
        detailname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Detailname);
        detailamount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Detailamount);
        adddetailtolist = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.addloglist);
        Date.setText(getDate());
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1,null,this);
        adapter = new DetailsAdapter(this,null);
        adddetailtolist.setAdapter(adapter);
        adddetailtolist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }
    private String getDate()
    {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE,dd-MMM-yyyy");
        String date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        return date;
    }
    public void addDetails(View view)
    {
        String Name = detailname.getText().toString();
        String Amount = detailamount.getText().toString();
        String date = Date.getText().toString();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DataProvider.Dname,Name);
        contentValues.put(DataProvider.DCategory,Debt);
        contentValues.put(DataProvider.Damount,Amount);
        contentValues.put(DataProvider.Ddate,date);
        contentValues.put(DataProvider.Per_In,logid);
        Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(DataProvider.ContentUri_Details,contentValues);
        Toast.makeText(AddLog.this, uri.toString()+"Value Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        NumberFormat currency = changeamount();
        TotalAmount.setText(currency.format(getAmount()));
    }

    private double getAmount()
    {
        ContentProviderClient client = getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient(DataProvider.ContentUri_Details);
        SQLiteDatabase db = ((DataProvider)client.getLocalContentProvider()).sqLiteDatabase;
        String query = "SELECT SUM(DAmount) FROM Details WHERE Per_In = "+logid;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        double amount = cursor.getDouble(0);
        cursor.close();
        client.release();
        return amount;
    }


    public NumberFormat changeamount()
    {
        Locale locale = new Locale("en","IN");
        NumberFormat currencyformat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
        return currencyformat;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuinflate = getMenuInflater();
        menuinflate.inflate(R.menu.addlogmenu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.done:
                saveData();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void saveData()
    {
        String name1 = name.getText().toString();
        String phone  = mobile.getText().toString();
        String address = city.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name1)||TextUtils.isEmpty(phone)||TextUtils.isEmpty(address))
        {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name1))
            {
                name.setError("Feild can not be Empty");
            }
           else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phone))
            {
                mobile.setError("Feild can not be Empty");
            }
           else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(address))
            {
                city.setError("Feild can not be Empty");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(DataProvider.Pname,name1);
            values.put(DataProvider.Pphone,phone);
            values.put(DataProvider.Paddress,address);
            values.put(DataProvider.PCategory,"Debt");
            values.put(DataProvider.Pamount,totamount);
            String where = DataProvider.PID+"=?";
            String[] whereargs = {String.valueOf(logid)};
           int a = getContentResolver().update(DataProvider.ContentUri_Person,values,where,whereargs);
            Toast.makeText(AddLog.this, String.valueOf(1)+"Value updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(returnback);
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(final int id, Bundle args)
    {
        String[] Projection = new String[]{DataProvider.DID,DataProvider.Dname,DataProvider.DCategory,DataProvider.Damount,DataProvider.Ddate};
        String selection = DataProvider.Per_In+"=?";
        String[] selectionargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(logid)};
        return new CursorLoader(this,DataProvider.ContentUri_Details,Projection,selection,selectionargs,null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data)
    {
       adapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader)
    {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

**Content Provider class:**

```
public class DataProvider extends ContentProvider
{
    static final String ProviderName = "com.example.mrudu.accounts.provider";
    static final String URLPerson = "content://"+ProviderName+"/Person_Detail";
    static final String URLDetails = "content://"+ProviderName+"/Details";
    static final Uri ContentUri_Person = Uri.parse(URLPerson);
    static final Uri ContentUri_Details = Uri.parse(URLDetails);
//Tables
private static String PTableName = "Person_Detail";
private static String DTableName = "Details";

public static long insertId = 0;

//Person_Detail Coloumns
public static String PID = "_id";
public static String Pname = "PName";
public static String Pphone = "PMobile";
public static String Paddress = "PCity";
public static String PCategory = "PCategory";
public static String Pamount = "PAmount";

//Details coloumn
public static String DID = "_id";
public static String Dname = "DName";
public static String Damount = "DAmount";
public static String Ddate = "DDate";
public static String DCategory = "DCategory";
public static String Per_In = "Per_In";

private static final int Person = 1;
private static final int Person_ID = 2;
private static final int Details = 3;
private static final int Details_Id = 4;

static UriMatcher uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
static
{
    uriMatcher.addURI(ProviderName,PTableName,Person);
    uriMatcher.addURI(ProviderName,PTableName+"/#",Person_ID);
    uriMatcher.addURI(ProviderName,DTableName,Details);
    uriMatcher.addURI(ProviderName,DTableName+"/#",Details_Id);
}

public static SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
private static String Databasename = "Accounts";
private static int DatabaseVersion = 1;

private class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, Databasename, null, DatabaseVersion);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase)
    {
        String Create_Person = " Create Table "+PTableName+"("+PID+" INTEGER PRIMARYKEY ,"+Pname+" TEXT ,"+Pphone+" TEXT ,"+Paddress+" TEXT ,"+PCategory+" TEXT ,"+Pamount+" REAL"+")";
        String Create_Details = " Create Table "+DTableName+"("+DID+" INTEGER PRIMARYKEY ,"+Dname+" TEXT ,"+DCategory+" TEXT ,"+Damount+" REAl ,"+Ddate+" TEXT ,"+Per_In+" INTEGER )";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(Create_Person);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(Create_Details);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1)
    {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("Drop TABLE if exists"+PTableName);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("Drop TABLE if exists"+DTableName);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreate()
{
    Context context = getContext();
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    sqLiteDatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return (sqLiteDatabase==null)?false:true;
}
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values)
{
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri))
    {
        case Person:
            long rowId = sqLiteDatabase.insert(PTableName,null,values);
            insertId = rowId;
            if (rowId>0)
            {
               Uri _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContentUri_Person,rowId);
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri,null);
                return _uri;
            }
            break;
        case Details:
            long rowId1 = sqLiteDatabase.insert(DTableName,null,values);
            if (rowId1>0)
            {
                Uri _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContentUri_Details,rowId1);
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri,null);
                return _uri;
            }
            break;
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                    String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)
{
    SQLiteQueryBuilder sqLiteQueryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri))
    {
        case Person_ID:
            sqLiteQueryBuilder.setTables(PTableName);
            sqLiteQueryBuilder.appendWhere(PID+ "="+ uri.getPathSegments().get(1));
            break;
        case Person:
            sqLiteQueryBuilder.setTables(PTableName);
            break;
        case Details_Id:
            sqLiteQueryBuilder.setTables(DTableName);
            sqLiteQueryBuilder.appendWhere(Per_In +"="+ uri.getPathSegments().get(1));
            break;
        case Details:
            sqLiteQueryBuilder.setTables(DTableName);
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteQueryBuilder.query(sqLiteDatabase,projection,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,sortOrder);
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(),uri);
    return cursor;

}
@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
                  String[] selectionArgs)
{
    int count = 0;
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri))
    {
        case Person:
            count = sqLiteDatabase.update(PTableName,values,selection,selectionArgs);
            break;
        case Person_ID:
            count = sqLiteDatabase.update(PTableName,values,PID+" = "+uri.getPathSegments().get(1)+(!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)?" AND (" + selection + ')':""),selectionArgs);
            break;
        case Details:
            count = sqLiteDatabase.update(DTableName,values,selection,selectionArgs);
            break;
        case Details_Id:
            count = sqLiteDatabase.update(DTableName,values,Per_In+" = "+uri.getPathSegments().get(1)+(!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)?" AND (" + selection + ')':""),selectionArgs);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri );
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri,null);
    return count;
}
@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    // Implement this to handle requests to delete one or more rows.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    // TODO: Implement this to handle requests for the MIME type of the data
    // at the given URI.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

**Cursor Recyclerview Adapter class:**

```
public abstract class CursorRecyclerViewAdapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {
    private Context mContext;

    private Cursor mCursor;

    private boolean mDataValid;

    private int mRowIdColumn;

    private DataSetObserver mDataSetObserver;

    public CursorRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        mContext = context;
        mCursor = cursor;
        mDataValid = cursor != null;
        mRowIdColumn = mDataValid ? mCursor.getColumnIndex("_id") : -1;
        mDataSetObserver = new NotifyingDataSetObserver();
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
        }
    }

    public Cursor getCursor() {
        return mCursor;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mDataValid && mCursor != null) {
            return mCursor.getCount();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        if (mDataValid && mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            return mCursor.getLong(mRowIdColumn);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void setHasStableIds(boolean hasStableIds) {
        super.setHasStableIds(true);
    }

    public abstract void onBindViewHolder(VH viewHolder, Cursor cursor);

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VH viewHolder, int position) {
        if (!mDataValid) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("this should only be called when the cursor is valid");
        }
        if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("couldn't move cursor to position " + position);
        }
        onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, mCursor);
    }

    /**
     * Change the underlying cursor to a new cursor. If there is an existing cursor it will be
     * closed.
     */
    public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        Cursor old = swapCursor(cursor);
        if (old != null) {
            old.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Swap in a new Cursor, returning the old Cursor.  Unlike
     * {@link #changeCursor(Cursor)}, the returned old Cursor is <em>not</em>
     * closed.
     */
    public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
        if (newCursor == mCursor) {
            return null;
        }
        final Cursor oldCursor = mCursor;
        if (oldCursor != null && mDataSetObserver != null) {
            oldCursor.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
        }
        mCursor = newCursor;
        if (mCursor != null) {
            if (mDataSetObserver != null) {
                mCursor.registerDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
            }
            mRowIdColumn = newCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id");
            mDataValid = true;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            mRowIdColumn = -1;
            mDataValid = false;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            //There is no notifyDataSetInvalidated() method in RecyclerView.Adapter
        }
        return oldCursor;
    }

    private class NotifyingDataSetObserver extends DataSetObserver {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            mDataValid = true;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated() {
            super.onInvalidated();
            mDataValid = false;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            //There is no notifyDataSetInvalidated() method in RecyclerView.Adapter
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Adapter class:**

```
public class Mainrow_Adapter extends CursorRecyclerViewAdapter<Mainrow_Adapter.ViewHolder>
{

    public Mainrow_Adapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView mName,mAmount;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainrowname);
            mAmount = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainrowAmount);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Mainrow_Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mainrow_layout,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Mainrow_Adapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor)
    {
        PersonDetails personDetails = PersonDetails.from(cursor);
        viewHolder.mName.setText(personDetails.getName());
        viewHolder.mAmount.setText(String.valueOf(personDetails.getAmount()));
    }


}
```

Comment: try it by calling `getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, null, this);` in `onResume `

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

then move below three lines from onCreate method to onResume(),

```
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1,null,this);
    adapter = new Mainrow_Adapter(this,null);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this will work

Comment: No, you should never put data processing codes in onResume, especially initLoader or setting adapters. Data processing logic should happen either inside onCreate() or onStart() methods.  onResume() will called every time when screen is turned on, or activity gains focus.

Comment: @vakman, he is exactly need that, when he turn on the screen the method should execute and refresh recycle view

Comment: It didnt work..I tried `getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, null, this);` it dosent work too

Comment: @Vickyexpert Actually the data is not updating in the database